# How to create an alias/map to a list of commands with arguments passed in

Tags: bash, shell, associative-array

I'm not sure what's the best approach to create this, but here's the flow of what I would like to do in this shell script. I basically have a list of commands/cli (passing in db connection string to postgres) and I want to create a shortcut by passing in an alias name along with another parameter (name) so that I can execute the command.

I'm trying to use an associative array, but not sure if this is the way to do this.

This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x


declare -A cluster_to_endpoint=(
  [c01]="psql -h test-endpoint1-us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -v v1=$NAME -p 5439 -f getTableDetails.sql"
  [c02]="psql -h test-endpoint2.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -v v1=$NAME -p 5439 -f getTableDetails.sql"
  [c03]="psql -h test-endpoint3.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -v v1=$NAME -p 5439 -f getTableDetails.sql"
)


while getopts ":c:n:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    c) cluster="$OPTARG";;
    n) name="$OPTARG";;
    *) usage
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac
done
```

I'm using `getopts` for passing in parameters.

I would like to execute it like so:  `./myscript.sh -c c01 -n foobar`

I would like to run this on macOS.

Comment: I'm getting these errors - `./myscript.sh: line 7: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]`

Comment: That error means your version of bash is too old to *have* associative arrays.

Comment: ...though commands shouldn't be stored as strings anyhow; see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). I'd strongly suggest defining a function for each of these. A `run_c01` function, a `run_c02` function, etc -- you can just invoke any matching `run_*` function that exists.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy- so are you saying create each command as a function and then it can also be invoked/executed as a parameter? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. `if declare -f run_"$cluster" >/dev/null 2>&1; then run_"$cluster"; fi`

Comment: BTW, I notice you're using `$NAME` but assigning to `name`; should probably standardize on all-lowercase across-the-board, if that's not already fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the newer version of bash, update the shebang to refer to it, ideally using `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` or `#!/opt/local/bin/bash` depending on your package manager. You can also use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` if the new bash is going to appear earlier in the PATH.

If you are going to use the system bash, you have to change your code to avoid associative arrays.

The version of bash that OS X ships with does not support associative arrays. This version of bash is available as `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh`. There is no obstacle to installing a later version of bash on OS X yourself (or using macports or homebrew).

```
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Associative arrays were introduced in version 4. This is because OS X is using the latest version of bash that's GPL v2.

As a workaround, you can use a function with `case` since you aren't adding new elements to your map at runtime:

```
cluster_to_endpoint() {
  case "$1" in
    c01)
      psql -h test-endpoint1-us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -v v1="$NAME" -p 5439 -f getTableDetails.sql
      ;;
    c02) 
      psql -h test-endpoint2.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -v v1="$NAME" -p 5439 -f getTableDetails.sql
      ;;
    c03)
      psql -h test-endpoint3.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -v v1="$NAME" -p 5439 -f getTableDetails.sql
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: I am running 4 - `$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>`

Comment: Bash 4 can still be installed on macOS, using Homebrew or another package manager.

Comment: @noober then use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: thanks guys, i'm progressing passed the errors and using this case statement. Although now the command is not working which i can manually run without any errors.  Am I passing in `$NAME`, which uses the switch `-n foobar` correctly? No error output anymore..just troubleshooting the command.

Comment: @noober does name contain whitespace? If it can, you need to quote `"$NAME"`. If you have more questions that arise from writing this particular script, try to write an example from scratch and ask it as a different question.

Comment: thanks @GregoryNisbet - its getting close, somehow its not interpreting the variables correctly. i'll continue to play with it and ask as another question if i don't figure it out... thanks again!